# What time-zone settings are followed for Timestamp logging by SQL Server deadlock event file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler

Deadlocks are happening in my database. I captured `Deadlock Graph` event using SQL Server Profiler tool. After the event gets captured you can save the entire information in *.xdl file. Here is a partial snippet of the entire XML it captured. I've garbled private data in the content below.

```
<deadlock-list>
    <deadlock victim="process6ff035c38">
        <process-list>
            <process id="process6ff035c38" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="PAGE: 5:1:294008 " waittime="3969" ownerId="4585079252" transactionname="SELECT" lasttranstarted="2016-09-09T16:25:57.270" XDES="0x1b3cefc50" lockMode="S" schedulerid="5" kpid="7676" status="suspended" spid="66" sbid="2" ecid="3" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2016-09-09T16:25:57.270" lastbatchcompleted="2016-09-09T16:25:57.270" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.270" clientapp="<garbled>" hostname="<garbled>" hostpid="7932" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="4585079252" currentdb="5" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
                <executionStack>
                    <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" sqlhandle="0x02000000164ea431e4d3c4ea517af1905e1a3ff28dc19d360000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
```

My simple question is about the various time stamps which are getting logged in this xml file e.g. `lasttranstarted`("2016-09-09T16:25:57.270"), `lastbatchstarted`("2016-09-09T16:25:57.270"), `lastbatchcompleted`("2016-09-09T16:25:57.270"). Are these values in GMT or local time zone based on the machine on which SQL Server in installed?

Is it possible to configure the time zone SQL Server profiler should use in the event logs it generates? The reason why I'm asking is because of the fact that some application log corresponding to this deadlock will also get created on application side. The application log files log time stamp of logs according to local time zone. If I don't have an idea on the time-zone SQL Server Profiler tool is following in its event logging then it will be difficult to correlate the two.

Comment: The timezone is in GMT.

Comment: @RohitKumar the timezone in the logged time stamps came out to be local time. Had it been GMT then a Z suffix would have been there representing Zero offset which is the case for Utc date time. Please look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was finally able to figure this out myself. Such a date time string `2016-09-09T16:25:57.270` is local time zone date time. You can see the various date time string format specifiers at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) link. The specific format I've asked in the post is `ISO 8601` format represented using `o` format specifier (Round-trip date/time pattern) in .Net. This is how it can look like:

- 2009-06-15T13:45:30.0000000Z - This value represents Utc time. Here `Z` represents Zero offset for GMT time.
- 2016-09-09T16:25:57.270 - This value ( in my question) represents local time-zone date-time.